# AngularJS controller returns form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, dynamicform

developers!

I decided to try Angular, so I want to make simple image uploading and editing app, in `MVC` (or close to it) architecture.

And I stuck on entrance point, because of I don't really know how to properly return filled `main form` from template.

As I think for now - I call `controller` function first, then it should call `mainService` function, which builds form, which uses 'imageUploadController' which using `imageUploadService`.

But I somesthing tells me that it's not okay to do things like that.

My main problem is how to get `uploadImageForm.html`, pass it to `index.html`, whithout links or includes (I just want to keep things separately)
make sure that services and controllerrs there working properly

How the best practices looks like in same situation?

Here's the code, hope it helps to see problem I got more clearly:

Here's my **index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="modernFilter">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Modern.Filters</title>
    <script src="asstes/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/components/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/shared/imageUploadController.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller = "mainController">
    <span>{{mainForm}}</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is app.js

```
'use strict';

// Define the `modern.filter` module
var modernFilterApp = angular.module('modernFilter', []);

//  Define main controller

modernFilterApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope, mainService){
    // Stores form data
    $scope.mainForm = null;

    // Returns main form template
    $scope.getMainForm = function(){
        $scope.mainForm = mainService.getMainForm();
    }

    // Call function on documentready
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $scope.getMainForm();

        //todo: is it even okay? but without it nothing happens
        $scope.$apply();
    })

}]);

// Define service

modernFilterApp.service('mainService', function(mainService){
    this.getMainForm = function(){
        // todo: how should I get template here?
        return "filled form template from here"
    }
});
```

Also I got template `imageUploadView`

```
<div ng-controller="imageUploadController">
<canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
<form action="">
    <input my-upload type="file" name="upload" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage()">
</form>
```

Cotroller and service for it (with example code, still debugging it)

```
modernFilterApp.controller('imageUploadController', ['$scope', 'imageUploadService', function($scope, imageUploadService) {
  // Stores image
  $scope.image = null;

  // Returns main form template
  $scope.uploadImage = function() {
    $scope.image = imageUploadService.handleImage(arguments);
  }

}]);

//  Define upload service

modernFilterApp.service('imageUploadService', function(imageUploadService) {

// Function handles uploaded files (dirty code)
this.handleImage = function(event) {
  var canvas = angular.element('#imageCanvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    reader = new FileReader(),
    img = new Image();

  canvas.width = img.width;

  canvas.height = img.height;
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  img.src = event.target.result;
  return reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont try to get the template from the controller.

You need to use directive. Make directive with its controller as imageUploadController , its template as imageUploadView and include it inside the index.html

Your html :-

```
<body ... >
  <my-directive></my-directive>
</body>
//include directive file,controller files
```

Directive :-

```
    .directive('myDirective', ['your service',function(your service) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'template url',
    link: function (scope) {

    },
    controller : function($scope){
    //your controller
    }
  };
}]);
```

[Refer here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Html will be automatically rendered in place of directive

Comment: Wow, thanks! But is there a way to separate contoller part form directive and keep it separately?

Comment: yes , controller : "controller name".But to build directives to have isolated scope , controller is used inside directive and not linking to other controller

Comment: oh, just like I should use
`var controllerName = ['$scope', function ($scope) { /** somestuff */}]`inside? 
so its okay to not have separate file for my controller?

Comment: at the place of //your controller , place the code present inside the imageUploadController. To create seperate file for controller , just do controller : "imageUploadController" in the directive and keep rest same , i.e yourApp.controller('imageUploadController',function($scope){})

Comment: for directive its meant to have controller defined at same place .. since its use is for creating reusable components along with dom manipulation

Comment: Wellp, now I got some circular dependencies here

Comment: have you removed div ng-controller=" .." from the template ?

Comment: nope, should i? how it would understand what function to use on change then?

Comment: It will use the controller provided in directive

Comment: Actually I removed service names from service declaration inside function signature and problem fixed. Another problem I got is firefox works okay but chrome says something about cross-origin stuff

Comment: Are you using http call ?

Comment: Path to my file in `templateUrl: 'template url'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119019/discussion-between-anmol-mittal-and-danil-gholtsman).